# Datediff in CosmosDb

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Hi There is there a way to achieve the datediff in a cosmosdb?

```
Select Datediff(day,c.datea, c.dateb) from c
```

Apparently the datediff is not a supported key word and i cant find a equivalent.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **`NO`** datediff available with **[`cosmosdb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference)**,

Instead you can use where clause if you want to query between two date ranges.

Comment: Pretty answer!!

Answer (score 5):

The DateTimeDiff is added in to cosmos db. Please refer this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-datetimediff

Answer (score 0):

Sajeetharan is correct. You could, however, store the dates as unix time stamps, then simply subtracting them would give you a datediff